# How to find range of a rational function without using graph?

Tags: functions

How to find range of

> $g(x)=\frac{5^x-5^{-x}}{5^x+5^{-x}}$

My idea was to find the inverse function and define the domain in it:
$y=\frac{5^x-5^{-x}}{5^x+5^{-x}}\Leftrightarrow y=\frac{5^x-\frac{1}{5^x}}{5^x+\frac{1}{5^x}}\Leftrightarrow y=\frac{5^{2x}-1}{5^{2x}+1}\Leftrightarrow y\left(5^{2x}+1\right)=5^{2x}-1\Leftrightarrow 5^{2x}y+y=5^{2x}-1\Leftrightarrow 5^{2x}y-5^{2x}=-y-1\Rightarrow 5^{2x}(y-1)=-(y+1)\Leftrightarrow 5^{2x}=\frac{-(y+1)}{(y-1)}\\\frac{-(y+1)}{(y-1)}>0\Rightarrow -(y+1)(y-1)>0 \Rightarrow y\in(-1;1)\Leftrightarrow\log_5 5^{2x}=\log_5\frac{-(y+1)}{(y-1)}\Leftrightarrow 2x=\log_5\frac{-(y+1)}{(y-1)}\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{1}{2}\log_5\frac{-(y+1)}{(y-1)}\\g^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log_5\frac{-(y+1)}{(y-1)}\\W_g=D_{g^{-1}}$
So range of $g(x)=\left(-1;1\right)$?
You could check if this solution makes sense and if there is a better way to find range of function?

Comment: Are you allowed to use derivatives?

Comment: Sorry for mistake in the title without graph, I haven't had derivatives yet, but I'd love to see your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1, show that $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing. You can calculate the derivative, and show that it is positive. Alternatively: $$g(x)=\frac{5^x-5^{-x}}{5^x+5^{-x}}=\frac{5^{2x}-1}{5^{2x}+1}=\frac{5^{2x}+1-2}{5^{2x}+1}=1-\frac{2}{5^{2x}+1}$$ 
You know that $5^{2x}$ is increasing, then $5^{2x}+1$, therefore $\frac 1{5^{2x}+1}$ is decreasing. When you subtract a smaller and smaller number, you get an increasing value.

Step 2, find the limits of $g(x)$ when $x$ goes to $\pm \infty$. In the equation above, in the last expression, $5^{-\infty}=0$, so $$g(-\infty)=1-\frac{2}{0+1}=-1$$. Similarly, when $x$ goes to infinity, $5^{2x}$ diverges to infinity, so $$g(\infty)=1-\frac{2}{\infty+1}=1$$

Comment: Thanks for alternative solution!

Answer (score 1):

This looks an awful lot like hyperbolic tangent.

$$
\tanh{(x)}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
$$

Let $x=u\ln{(5)}$ and substitute this into the equation for hyperbolic tangent.

$$
\tanh{(u\ln{(5)})}=\frac{e^{u\ln{(5)}}-e^{-u\ln{(5)}}}{e^{u\ln{(5)}}+e^{-u\ln{(5)}}}=\frac{5^u-5^{-u}}{5^u+5^{-u}}
$$

Hyperbolic tangent has a range $(-1,1)$.

Another useful technique is to take what you had toward the start,

$$
\frac{5^{2x}-1}{5^{2x}+1}
$$

But just square the 5’s.

$$
\begin{align}
y=&\frac{25^x-1}{25^x+1}\\
\\
\text{and }\\
\\
\,\lim_{x\to\infty}&{\frac{25^x-1}{25^x+1}}=1\\
\lim_{x\to-\infty}&{\frac{25^x-1}{25^x+1}}=-1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x)=\frac{5^x-5^{-x}}{5^x+5^{-x}}$$

Note $g(0)=0$.

For $x > 0$, $g(x)< 1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 1$. Hence, for $x > 0$, $g(x) \in (0, 1)$.

Since $x \ne 0 \implies g(x) g(-x) = -1$, then, for $x < 0$, $g(x) \in (-1, 0)$.

Hence the range of $g(x) = (-1, 1)$.